# Iterated logarithm to the $n - 1$ of the auto tetration n^^n

Tags: logarithms, tetration

I'm considering the sequence

1. $0 = \log(1)$
2. $\log\left(2^2\right)$
3. $\log\left(\log\left(3^{3^3}\right)\right)$
4. $\log\left(\log\left(\log\left(4^{4^{4^4}}\right)\right)\right)$

I tried solving this using Python and I get lots of $\log(x < 0)$ problems. I thought they were mostly fence post and recursion type errors, so I debugged my code but still the latest [iteration](https://pastebin.com/HitH1N8U) has those problems for $n > 5$ or so.

I'm beginning to suspect that the iterated logs are too powerful, even when taken down a notch, and that I should do something to the argument to keep things finite. My first theory, on discovering a recursive solution, was that my sequence was increasing but I'm not at all sure anymore

Just to clarify: by iterated logarithm I mean $\log(\log(\log(... \text{Self tetration}, n^{n^{\dots}} )))$, is just $1$, $2^2$, $3^{3^3}$, ...

Iterated logs to the $n$ are provably overkill and iterated logs to the $n-2$ fail to tame the power tower.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @saulspatz I'm not proficient in MathJax. I'm leaning on the community to edit my post if it has any value at all.

Comment: @Emanuel: whoa there, I didn't say this wasn't a question, I just wanted to know what your question was. Obviously you want to know something about this sequence but what? Do you want a proof that it's increasing? Do you want someone to debug your Python code? (I can't help you with that part, unfortunately.) Do you want someone to propose modifications to the sequence? If so, modifications that accomplish what?

Comment: Cheers for the edit @Leucippus!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, just paranoid from repeated exposure to stackexchange. Didn't mean to single you out like that.

My immediate question is if this is a well-behaved, increasing sequence. And if so, how can I prove it? And what's wrong with my code!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming these are natural logarithms, although as it turns out the base of the logarithm doesn't matter much. Write $\log^k$ for the iterated (natural) logarithm and $n \upuparrows k$ for tetration. Note that with base-$n$ logarithms we clearly have

$$\log^k_n (n \upuparrows n) = (n \upuparrows (n-k)).$$

For $n \ge 3$ we have $\log n > 1$ and hence $\log_n x < \log x$, which gives

$$\log^{n-1}(n \upuparrows n) > \log \log_n^{n-2} (n \upuparrows n) = \log n^n = n \log n.$$

In particular there should in principle be no problems with taking logs of negative numbers, but I don't know what any particular piece of Python code might be doing to compute logs here.

But we can say more than this: it turns out that the base of practically every logarithm in the sequence except the outermost one doesn't matter, so the above is a pretty accurate approximation, which means

$$\boxed{ \log^{n-1} (n \upuparrows n) \approx \log n^n = n \log n }$$

so this sequence is increasing except for possibly the first few terms which can be checked by hand. To give an idea of how this works here's the $n = 4$ case. We get

$$\log 4^{4^{4^4}} = 4^{4^4} \log 4$$
$$\log \log 4^{4^{4^4}} = 4^4 \log 4 + \log \log 4.$$

Here $4^4 \log 4 \approx 355$ and $\log \log 4 \approx 0.326$ is much smaller in comparison so can be safely ignored when we take the next logarithm, hence

$$\log \log \log 4^{4^{4^4}} \approx 4 \log 4 + \log \log 4 \approx 4 \log 4.$$

In general we can argue by induction that $\log^k (n \upuparrows n) \approx (n \upuparrows (n-k)) \log n$. The error terms are quite tiny in comparison to how big the power towers are until we get to the outermost or *maybe* the second-to-outermost log. I can be more precise about this if you want.

Comment: Does the base really matter that much?

Or maybe that's just it. I've been working with the natural logarithm. If only I had chosen base X my series would have been increasing...

Well. tbqh, I just don't think the base matters all that much. After all, it's just a constant multiplication per power tower level. Surely the power tower will eventually dominate if you don't iterate your logs enough.

A dependence on the base is just nature's way of instructing you to change the iteratation count of the log.

Comment: @Emanuel: yes, I am saying exactly that the base doesn't really matter. The series is still increasing (once the first few terms have been checked).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. So my intuition that this series is increasing is vindicated? That means my code is still buggy...

Comment: @Emanuel: yes, the sequence is approximately $n \log n$ as I said.

Comment: Nice! And I'll give you my first-borne if you can correct my faulty code. I spent like 2 hours debugging that recursion :D

Comment: Man. as I'm slowly digesting your answer I really feel bad for lashing out. That was uncalled for. Thanks man, you may have saved me a sleepless night!

Comment: @Emanuel: no worries, I'm not always as nice as I'd like to be on the internet either. You're welcome! I don't know what's going on in your code though. Naively I'd expect you'd be getting overflow errors.

Comment: I have updated my code. It's still at https://pastebin.com/HitH1N8U I It's still buggy because it always eventually calls log(x < 0) for logtetra(n > 5). ANyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

*This answer is just an expansion of Qiaochu Yuan's answer to get a memorizable recursive form and to have a handful of actual values*

I've explicated Qiaochu Yuan's approach with one more term, for instance for $m=4$ computing
$$ \log^{\circ3} (\;^44) = 4 \log(4)+ \log^{\circ2}(4)+\log\left(1+\frac{\log^{\circ2}(4)}{\log(4)} \frac1{\;^24} \right) \tag 1
$$
So this is a bit more precise, and suffices, when we work with more than the usual *~20* digits precision.

To have the scheme for larger $m$ handable, I've done the following notation and computation:

---

For the following, let's denote for the logarithm $\lambda (x) := \log(x)$, and $ \lambda^{\circ h}(x):=\log^{\circ h}(x)$ for the $h$-fold iterated $\log()$.
Moreover, we allow to omit the parentheses for a simple argument like $\lambda m := \log(m)$, $\lambda\lambda m := \log(\log(m))$ and so on.

Then for $m=2$ we have
$$ \lambda^{\circ 1}(\;^22) = 
  \;^12 \lambda2  = 2 \lambda 2  \tag 2
$$

For $m=3$ we have
$$ \lambda^{\circ 2}(\;^33) = 
  \;^13 \lambda3 \left(
       1+
          { \lambda\lambda3
           \over
           \;^13 \lambda3 }
 \right) = 3\lambda3+ \lambda\lambda 3  \tag 3
$$

For $m=4$ we have
$$ \lambda^{\circ 3}(\;^44) = 
  \;^14 \lambda4 \left(
       1+
          { \lambda\lambda4
               + \lambda \left(
                           1+{ \lambda\lambda4 \over \;^24 \lambda4}
                         \right) 
           \over
           \;^14 \lambda4 }
 \right) \\
 = 4 \lambda4 + \lambda \lambda 4+ \lambda\left(1+ {\lambda\lambda4\over \;^24 \lambda 4}\right)  \tag 4
$$
For $m=5$ we have
$$ \lambda^{\circ 4}(\;^55) = 
 \;^15 \lambda5 \left(
       1+
          { \lambda\lambda5
               + \lambda \left(
                           1+{ \lambda\lambda5  
                                  + \color{red}{ \lambda\left( 1+ {\lambda\lambda5\over \;^35 \lambda5} \right)}
                               \over 
                               \;^25 \lambda5}
                         \right) 
           \over
           \;^15 \lambda5 }
 \right) \\
=   5 \lambda5 + \lambda \lambda 5+ \lambda\left(1+ {\lambda\lambda5 + \varepsilon \over \;^25 \lambda 5}\right) \qquad \varepsilon \lt 10^{-2000} \tag 5$$
Here, the $\color{red} {\text{red}}$ part might be set to zero - although Pari/GP can evaluate it to the small number $1.5472633343566660957 \cdot 10^{-2185}$.

I think, it is obvious enough, to see how this recursive expression extends for the case $m=6$ and $m \gt 6$.

***So in general*** we could -with very good approximation to thousands of digits- denote the general case for $m \ge 4$:
$$  \lambda^{\circ m-1}(\;^mm) = \;^1m \lambda m \left(
       1+
          { \lambda\lambda m
               + \lambda \left(
                           1+{ \lambda\lambda m  \color{red}{+ \varepsilon} \over \;^2 m \lambda m}
                         \right) 
           \over
           \;^1m \lambda m }
 \right) \qquad \phantom {aaaaaaaaaaaa}\\
=   m \lambda m + \lambda \lambda m+ \lambda\left(1+ {\lambda\lambda m + \varepsilon \over \;^2m \lambda m}\right) \qquad m \ge 4,\varepsilon \lt 10^{-2000}   \tag 6
$$
For actual evaluation of course set $\varepsilon=0$.

---

Pari/GP can evaluate the rhs of this formula up to large $m$ and here is a short list of results:

```
   m   f(m)
   1                      1
   2  1.3862943611198906188
   3  3.3898846936210280904
   4  5.8727316593473939578
   5  8.5231691718927068792
   6  11.333761872486528355
   7  14.287101269386856237
   8  17.367631722509864240
   9  20.562216205127370811
  10  23.859883375224634209
  11  27.251439383707043270
  12  30.729114890821370757
  13  34.286280381748089855
  14  37.917224395890985590
  15  41.616981909484545859
  16  45.381200996374726095
  17  49.206038373730453973
  18  53.088076771932640857
  19  57.024258903684450970
  20  61.011834171444768572
```

The Pari/GP-program used is this (I set internal computational precision to *200* dec digits by default):

```
{list=matrix(20,2);
 for(m=1,20, 
    for(dummy=1,1,
                     if(m==1,t1=m;       break());
         lm=log(m);  if(m==2,t1=m*lm;    break());
         llm=log(lm);if(m==3,t1=m*lm+llm;break());
         t3=log(1+0+0); /* t3=log(1+llm/lm/m^m^m+ log(1+ ...(recursion)...));*/
         t2=log(1+llm/lm/m^m+t3);
         t1=m*lm+llm+t2;
       );
   list[m,]=[m,t1];
   );  }
               \\ -----------------
print(list);
```

Comment: This is so nice. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Gottfried very nice !